# для чего атрибут media в теге <a>?

Tags: html5, веб-программирование

помогитье пожалуйста. я попробовал такоий код, но результат одинаковы, нечего особенного не увидел.
Есть какой то особенность в нем которий можете обеснить мне?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>Hi</title>
    
        </head>
        <body>
            
            <ul>
                <li>
            <a href="https://images.drive.ru/i/0/5d76118aec05c42518000007.jpg" media="min-width: 320px">
                <img src="html.png" alt="">
            </a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="https://images.drive.ru/i/0/5d76118aec05c42518000007.jpg" media="min-width: 1382px">
                <img src="poqrhtml.png" alt="">
            </a>
            </li>
            </ul>

        </body>
    </html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: такого атрибута нет - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: спасибо за ответ.